# Class 'Event' has no instance getter 'docs' error on flutter realtime database

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I have such a data on realtime database. I was trying to show all values of "il" on the dropdown menu but I faced this error: "Class 'Event' has no instance getter 'docs'.
Receiver: Instance of 'Event'. Tried calling: docs"

[image]

```
class _PaymentState extends State<Payment> {
  final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase(databaseURL:"abc").reference();
  var city= "x";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: databaseReference.child("Sheet1").orderByChild("il").onValue,
        builder: (context,snapshot) {
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Container();  
                  }             
                       
         return DropdownButton(
                    isExpanded: false,
                    value: city,
                    items: snapshot.data.docs.map((value) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem(
                        value: value.get('il'),
                        child: Text('${value.get('il')}'),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                          onChanged: (value) {
                      debugPrint('selected onchange: $value');
                      setState(
                        () {
                          debugPrint('make selected: $value');
                          city = value;
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  );
                },      
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you created any Event class?

Comment: @Diwyansh No I didn't create

Comment: Can you show on which line this error is appearing?

Comment: @Diwyansh    items: snapshot.data.docs.map((value)

Comment: Please print sanpshot.data and updated it's response in your question.